problem app music with read media audio (playlist does not appear)
I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1D1Jo1sLBMo&t=320s&ab_channel=EasyTuto
but I can't get my playlist or the authorization request but being on Android 13 I did the tests below
I replaced "READ EXTERNAL STORAGE" on the manifest and on main activity by "READ MEDIA AUDIO"
Now, I have the window that asks for authorization, but even if I indicate OK, my playlist is not displayed and it tells me the text "MUSIC NOT FOUND"
for info: android studio code java
Who can tell me what the problem is...
I've been at this for days, I'm lost....
thank you everyone

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I struggled with different versions/permissions for a long time. In the end my configuration is
Manifest:





    and java code I called "Startup" (not full method extract)
        String[] permissions ={READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_MEDIA_AUDIO};
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Arrays.toString(permissions))
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
        } else {
            first_messageDialog(mContext.getString(R.string.attention), mContext.getString(R.string.androidQ));
            Intent i = new Intent(this, PlaylistMainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                this.finish();
            }



    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST:
            if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        || (grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                        || (grantResults[2] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED))
                {
            //      Log.i("PERMISSION RESULTS", "Read Storage " + grantResults[0] + " Write Storage " + grantResults[1]);
                    Intent i = new Intent(this, PlaylistMainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    this.finish();
                }
                break;
            }

This does away with all the stupid version checking and just gets on with the job if appropriate.

thank you very much!!!
